# Traversing stack and retrieving main arguments

Tags: c

Given the size of the code of the main function in bytes passed as a parameter to a function, what is the best way to get to the base address for the main code and retrieve the first char * in the argv array?

Answer (score 3):

There is no portable way to accomplish this.  It depends entirely on what platform you are using and what calling convention is used.

That said, the *size* of the code in `main()` shouldn't ordinarily have any impact on the layout of the stack because the code is not located on the stack.

The best way to get `argv` from a function called from `main()` is to have that function take a `const char**` as a parameter and pass the `argv` into it.